# How to use a listbox and dropdown list in a single ascx page and access it an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, ascx, dropdownbox

I want to use multiple controls like dropdown list, listbox, radiobutton list in a single ascx page instead of using multiple ascx pages and wanted to access it in an aspx page.

Comment: Do you want to display all the control at a same time or conditional base ?

Comment: So, what is your problem? you can do that. You can add multiple controls on a usercontrol(.ascx) and then add this .ascx to a page(.aspx). What is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to access these controls in the aspx page.How can i differentiate which control i want to use in the aspx page.For Eg. I want to use dropdown list and list box at the same time.

Comment: When you insert your ascx control in your page, give him a name. After that go to page code behind and type this.myAscxControlName.whatEverControlName. Make sure that you expose public properties in your ascx that returns inner controls

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show that in a code since i am new with user controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a user control MyControl.ascx with these controls:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MyControl" %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn" runat="server">Link Button</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn" runat="server" Text="Radio Button" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Dropdown"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now MyControl.ascx.cs page code: Create public properties for each control and set them

public DropDownList dropdown { get; set; }

```
public RadioButton radioButton { get; set; }

public LinkButton linkbutton { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCtrlProperties();
}

private void SetCtrlProperties(){
    dropdown = ddl;
    radioButton = rbtn;
    linkbutton = lbtn;
}
```

Now if you are placing this on a page named default.aspx and want to hide all control on a button clicked from .aspx page then .aspx page code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <uc1:MyControl ID="MyControl1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hide" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

and Default.aspx.cs page code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyControl1.dropdown.Visible = false;
            MyControl1.radioButton.Visible = false;
            MyControl1.linkbutton.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one user control  named it and add all the controls which you want to show and are common for some pages.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ControlsDemo.CustomControl" %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server">Link Button</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioBtn" runat="server" Text="Radio Button" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And now you have to declare that user control in your aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ControlsDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlsDemo.ControlsDemo"%>

    <%@ Register Src="~/CustomControl.ascx" TagName="CControl" TagPrefix="ucCtrl" %>
```

Now you can use it any where in that aspx page

```
<ucCtrl="CControl" runat="server" />
```